# OCMock - trying to mock NSEntityDescription

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmanagedobjectcontext, ocmock, nsentitydescription

in order to test a managed class I tried to create an instance in a unit test by first trying to mock NSEntityDescription and NSManagedObjectContext.

```
id mockEntityDesc = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[NSEntityDescription class]];
id mockManagedObjectContext = [OCMockObject mockForClass:NSManagedObjectContext.class];
```

But before I can get any further I get the following error when test is run;

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in CallsCoordinatorTests.o
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectContext", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in CallsCoordinatorTests.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any advice please?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your unit test target is not linking with the Core Data framework.